# Skype Desktop Win 8.1 Notifications Bubbles Broken?

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, skype, notifications

I cant seem to get skype desktop on windows 8.1 to show bubbles for notifications like it did in previous windows versions.

I have already set "Control Panel--->All Control Panel Items--->Notification Area Icons"
  - To "Show icon and notifications"
[image]
Also in skype settings I have turned on the notifications for "comes online" and "sends me a message"
Even the example appears correctly.
[image]

But when I actually do receive a message the taskbar icon and system tray icon only blink with no "BUBBLE"
[image]

However I do receive the "BUBBLE" when a contact comes online.

Is this just broken in windows 8? or am I missing something?